# Java apps auto-registration

Tags: java, performance

I have a Monitoring Application/Tool (Java) that gets status data from jmx calls (polling). This tool is used for multiple environments where same application are located on different servers and have different jmx ports. Thus i maintain an environment specific configuration file for all applications to monitor. Needless to say it is not efficient. I need to implement a auto-registration of monitored applications within my Monitoring tool. Can you give me ideas on best efficient way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What possible approaches have you looked into? Is there a specific problem that you've come across?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on Coda Hale's Metrics: http://metrics.codahale.com/getting-started/. It might be a good starting point.